# Injectivity Theorem of Covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

This is theorem 11.16 (Injectivity Theorem) in Introduction to Topological Manifolds by John Lee.

> Let $q:E\to X$ be a covering map. For any point $e\in E$, the induced homomorphism $q_*:\pi_1(E,e)\to \pi_1(X,q(e))$ is injective.

That shows the fundamental group of a covering space is isomorphic to a certain subgroup of the fundamental group of the base. I can understand the proof but I have trouble understanding why the fundamental groups of the base and covering space are different. It seems that the fundamental group of the covering space became "less" than that of the base.

By fundamental group, my intuition boils down to different kinds of loops that cannot be deformed to each other. So does that mean by looking at the covering space $E$, we lost some kind of loop? However, I have trouble thinking of a concrete example. Would anyone elaborate a bit? I'd appreciate it if there's an explicit example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let me use a basic example : the covering $\mathbb R \to \mathbb S^1 = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ (simply given by the canonical projection).
In some sense, even if $\mathbb R$ is "bigger" than $\mathbb S^1$, it is "simpler" for the fondamental group : $1 \to \mathbb Z$ is, indeed, injective.

More generally, if I denote $\widetilde X$ the universal covering of $X$, then, using the usual order of coverings, $X \leq E \leq \widetilde X$, so $E$ is closer to $\widetilde X$ than $X$ is.

Comment: That makes sense! Since we have lifting correspondence $\Phi_{e_0}:\pi_1(B,b_0)\to p^{-1}(b_0)$, that means the preimage of loops in base $B$ might not be a loop in the covering space anymore. So we are "losing" some loops in the covering space.